# How can I send an email based on a new primary key being generated through Django?

Tags: python, django, email, key

I am wanting to send the user an email whenever a new primary key is generated in Django. My code in **Models.py:**

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    product = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    vendor = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    dollar_amount = models.FloatField()
    item_number = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

**I have it coded to where I can send an email every time my page is refreshed**

```
email = EmailMessage('Purchase Order System', 'your message here', to=['youremail@gmail.com'])
email.send()
```

**But how can I make it so that every time a new Primary key is generated, send an email?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/).

```
from django.db.models import signals

def send_email_on_new_order(instance, created, raw, **kwargs):
    # Fixtures or updates are not interesting.
    if not created or raw:
        return

    # `instance` is your PurchaseOrder instance.
    email = EmailMessage('Purchase Order System', 'your message here', to=['youremail@gmail.com'])
    email.send()

signals.post_save.connect(send_email_on_new_order, sender=PurchaseOrder, dispatch_uid='send_email_on_new_order')
```

You have to paste this code somewhere it will be executed during loading django, e.g. `models.py`

Example `models.py`:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import signals

class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    product = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    vendor = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    dollar_amount = models.FloatField()
    item_number = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

def send_email_on_new_order(instance, created, raw, **kwargs):
    # Fixtures or updates are not interesting.
    if not created or raw:
        return

    # `instance` is your PurchaseOrder instance.
    email = EmailMessage('Purchase Order System', 'your message here', to=['youremail@gmail.com'])
    email.send()

signals.post_save.connect(send_email_on_new_order, sender=PurchaseOrder, dispatch_uid='send_email_on_new_order')
```

Comment: I'm getting an error saying 
"NameError: name 'PurchaseOrder' is not defined" I apologize if this is a terrible question, as I am both new to Python and Django.

Comment: Put `from django.db.models import signals` at the top of your `models.py` file, whilst the rest of the code below your `PurchaseOrder` definition. Check my answer for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Listen to the `post_save` signal.

```
from django.db.models import signals
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(signals.post_save, sender=PurchaseOrder)
def email_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        email = EmailMessage('Purchase Order System', 'your message here', to=['youremail@gmail.com'])
        email.send()
```

Or define a custom `save` method in your model.

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Check if this is a new key
        if not self.pk:
            email = EmailMessage('Purchase Order System', 'your message here', to=['youremail@gmail.com'])
            email.send()
        super(PurchaseOrder, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

@voithos is correct that this a custom save is a good way to approach the problem. However, according to a strict answering of the question, the email is technically sent *just* before the Primary Key is created. That may not matter, though if it does, I would order the code something like the following:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    email = False  # Don't email by default
    # Check if this is a new key
    if not self.pk:
        email = EmailMessage('Purchase Order System', 'your message here', to=['youremail@gmail.com'])
    super(PurchaseOrder, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if email:  # Email was created, and we have a new Primary Key, so send now.
        email.send()
```

NB: If you need a way to reference the newly created instance (eg, the Email needs to contain a link that includes the just-created Primary Key), I would personally go with the signal approach offered by @kroolik.